# AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'DATABASE_ENGINE'

Tags: python, django

Im new to django and python, trying to run a piece of django code on my system but im running into these problems , im running version 2.7 python and v1.4 django

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Running in development mode.
Running in development mode.
Running in development mode.
Running in development mode.
Validating models...

HACKUING USER MODEL
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x101981e50>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 158, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 64, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 88, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/Kinnovate/Desktop/fsdjango/platformsite/notices/models.py", line 9, in <module>
    from common.fields import PickleField
  File "/Users/Kinnovate/Desktop/fsdjango/platformsite/common/fields/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pickle import *
  File "/Users/Kinnovate/Desktop/fsdjango/platformsite/common/fields/pickle.py", line 27, in <module>
    mysql_backend = settings.DATABASE_ENGINE == 'mysql'
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 186, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'DATABASE_ENGINE'
```

this is the part of settings.py relevant to the question

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'database.sqlite3'), # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
 }
```

how do i fix this?

Comment: Please provide the model code to check the type of fields in model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is `/Users/Kinnovate/Desktop/fsdjango/platformsite/common/fields/pickle.py`? Is it your code? Then you have an error in it, because you really don't have `DATABASE_ENGINE` in your seetings. Use `settings.DATABASES['default']['ENGINE']` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing something

Because as your backtrace your database must be `mysql`.

```
File "/Users/Kinnovate/Desktop/fsdjango/platformsite/common/fields/pickle.py", line 27, in <module>
    mysql_backend = settings.DATABASE_ENGINE == 'mysql'
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 186, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
```

Because its enter in `mysql_backend = settings.DATABASE_ENGINE == 'mysql'` line.

As per your settings its `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',` so it must be enter in `sqlite` please check your app because it might be possible that your `settings.py` might be refer from another place.